# Formula for a calculated field to convert string to date()in share point

Tags: sharepoint-2010, calculated-columns, date-arithmetic

we have a list where the date is saving as YYYY-MM-DD format in a column of single of text. Now i need a  formula for calculated column of Date type to save the string date(YYYY-MM-DD) to DD-MM-YYYY of date type.

any help or suggestions please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to mess with date conversions you can convert your text string (in column D ) with the DATE( Year , Month , Day ) Function:

```
=DATE( LEFT(D,4) , MID(D,6,2) , RIGHT(D,2) )
```

The TEXT function gives you the notation you are looking for

```
=TEXT(   DATE( LEFT(D,4) , MID(D,6,2) , RIGHT(D,2))   , "dd-mm-yyyy")
```

If your text string also has 'YYYY-M-D' notations you need to do some extra work to find the 2 - (dash) separators and extract the Month and Day

To get the Month:
*(starting at the 6th character in the second FIND gets you past the first dash character)*

```
=MID( D , FIND("-",D)+1 , FIND("-",D,6)-FIND("-",D)-1 )
```

To get the Day:

```
=RIGHT(D, LEN(D) - FIND("-",D) + 1 )
```

Year still is

```
= LEFT( D , 4 )
```

Unless it can be written as YY, you then need:

```
= LEFT( D , FIND(D,"-")-1 )
```

I will leave it to you to combine it into one Calculated Formula

**Note on non-english sites the , separator is usually a ; (semi-colon)**

*Please mark the answer as answered to keep StackOverflow structured*

Comment: Dear Danny Thanks for the help. I have date in string field with dd/mm/yyyy(27/02/2014) i need the same date string in date format but i am getting a error for the dates having more that 12 while using the above formulas. can you plz help me in this regards, T tried the above these formula =IF(ISBLANK([ Date]),"12/12/2020",TEXT(LEFT([Date],2),MID([Date],4,2),RIGHT([Date],4)))

Comment: This function you quote: =IF(ISBLANK([ Date]),"12/12/2020",TEXT(LEFT([Date],2),MID([Date],4,2),RIGHT([Date],4))) does not have the DATE function in it like in my example.  If you have problems with 'dates having more then 12' .. then that is a Month and not a Day notation you are using. Note: your SharePoint localization setting (see site setting) determine if dates are in dd/mm or mm/dd notation.